# Jenkins Pipeline - Call functions in shared jar

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-shared-libraries

So here is my project setup

1. A separate groovy project
2. Multiple pipelines

All the pipeline scripts refer to the shared groovy project. I went through the shared libraries and all of the needs to be registered in Jenkins global configuration.

Is there any way to do without it? I tried using Grab but ended up with the error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: No suitable ClassLoader found for grab
```

Comment: the way jenkins pipeline shared libraries are supposed to be distributed and consumed is well documented. What is the reason you're not using the documented path?

Comment: Here: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/

Comment: All examples are for Global Shared Library. Mine is simple but doesn't work. I have library extension.jar copied into my workspace. I need to refer the library through the pipeline code.

Comment: I also don't want to refer to the git project as I have lot of dependencies in my project and would prefer to build a fatjar out of it. Please let me know if there are any solutions

Comment: It's not clear to me what problems you are having. What are the limitations of using  _Shared Library_ that are limiting you right now? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Shared libraries are of Groovy code. How did you put it in a `java`-jar file? Can you explain?

Comment: agree with @mvk_il, use the documented Jenkins Shared Library approach.

Comment: I'm voting to close this as it is unclear what you are asking.